# How to fix plot points for scipy and matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scipy

Here's a picture of the x and y below:[image]

```
x = np.array([6, 3, 5, 2, 1, 4, 9, 7, 8])
y = np.array([2, 1, 3 ,5 ,3 ,9 ,8, 10, 7])
```

With the x and y points for the code above, it works, but with x and y below, it doesn't output the points like the code above. I think it's because the x and y code below is too big of a number maybe?

Here's a picture for the code below:
[image]

```
import time, os, matplotlib
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([])
y = np.array([113.1350,113.2600,113.6000,113.6600,115.1600,114.7700,118.8100,118.3500,118.5500,118.6150,119.3765,119.3500,119.0000,118.7650,117.9300,118.2100,117.7500,117.4400,117.8450,117.7466,117.4500,116.9600,116.2600,116.8100,116.8950])

for line in np.array([
'2020-04-07 16:00:00','2020-04-07 16:01:00','2020-04-07 16:02:00','2020-04-07 16:03:00','2020-04-07 16:04:00',
'2020-04-07 16:05:00','2020-04-07 16:06:00','2020-04-07 16:07:00','2020-04-07 16:08:00','2020-04-07 16:09:00',
'2020-04-07 16:10:00','2020-04-07 16:11:00','2020-04-07 16:12:00','2020-04-07 16:13:00','2020-04-07 16:14:00',
'2020-04-07 16:15:00','2020-04-07 16:16:00','2020-04-07 16:17:00','2020-04-07 16:18:00','2020-04-07 16:19:00',
'2020-04-07 16:20:00','2020-04-07 16:21:00','2020-04-07 16:22:00','2020-04-07 16:23:00','2020-04-07 16:24:00',]):
    d=str(line).replace('T',' ')
    p='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    epoch = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(d,p)))
    x = np.append(x, epoch)



# sort the data in x and rearrange y accordingly
sortId = np.argsort(x)
x = x[sortId]
y = y[sortId]

# this way the x-axis corresponds to the index of x
plt.plot(x-1, y)
plt.show()
maxm = argrelextrema(y, np.greater)  # (array([1, 3, 6]),)
minm = argrelextrema(y, np.less)  # (array([2, 5, 7]),)

from scipy.signal import find_peaks

peaks, _ = find_peaks(y)
troughs, _ = find_peaks(-y)

# this way the x-axis corresponds to the index of x
plt.plot(x-1, y)
plt.plot(peaks, y[peaks], "x")
# plt.plot(troughs, y[troughs], "x")
plt.show()
```

Comment: `it doesn't output the points like the code above` - What exactly is wrong? How is it deficient? Did you write that code? It *makes a plot* for me.

Comment: @wwii I added pictures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the indices **for** the x-values instead of using them to **select** x values.

Change

```py
plt.plot(peaks, y[peaks], "x")
```

To

```py
plt.plot(x[peaks], y[peaks], "x")
```